# views_get_current_view performance

Tags: 7, views

Does this function [`views_get_current_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_current_view/7.x-3.x) inside views header or footer (to count rows number for example) means running the same view twice?
 Or is it somewhat simplified version of running full view? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, you want to display count rows in header an footer of the view ?

Comment: @berramou Or pull any data based on current view. My question is if this function means that the same view will run again just to get me this info (for example row number) or not.

Comment: If you're using Views PHP filter thats bad for performance. Even the [projects image](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/IMG_20140930_162850.jpg) says so.

Comment: @NoSssweat what do you suggest in this case then? thank you

Comment: Views provides some tokens I think its `@count` that you can use in the header. If its something else other than counting use `template_preprocess_views_view` or `hook_views_pre_render` and do your logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is just a wrapper for this function:
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_set_current_view/7.x-3.x
which will just return a reference to a static code cache.

Conclusion: no view gets run, it's just grabbing a copy of what's already been created.

In general, views is very efficient in such cases.

But I'd tend to agree with @berramou that you might have a better way of accomplishing what you really, really want.

Comment: thank you. By better solution you mean adding this code to module?

Comment: Yes, you don't want to be putting code in the header/footer. But you might instead be able to accomplish what you want without custom code - most things I ever want to do with views have already been done and documented if you look hard enough.